# Does anyone recognise this seemingly mean-reverting stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

$$d\sqrt{v} = (\alpha - \beta \sqrt{v})dt + \delta dB_{t}$$

Comment: Is $\delta$ in $\delta d B_t$ a constant or a typo?

Comment: @Bob Jansen $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$ are constants.

Comment: That's simply an O-H for $u:=\sqrt{v}$ no?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw It does look like an OU, but why the odd $\sqrt{v}$?

Comment: Well without the source it is difficult to say. But likely because the process $v$ is defined such that $v>0$ otherwise the SDE is ill-defined.

Comment: It seems like a variant of the vol process in the Stein and Stein model.